# Поставить автоинкремет

Tags: postgresql

Не могу поставить автоинкремет на id.
Нет типов типа serial.
Какие ещё способы?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Какие ещё способы?* Создать таблицу SQL-запросом.

Comment: Уже создал таблицу и связи. Запросом я могу поменять тип данных?

Comment: *Запросом я могу поменять тип данных?* Конечно. PostgreSQL вполне себе поддерживает [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html)...

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое